# How to put button in top right og jpane

Tags: java, swing, layout

According to your instruction i decided to use GridBagLayout, but i also face a problem in positioning buttons in a panel the button expected to be at top right, But it is displayed in the center, Please tell me what is the problem in my code`

```
import java.awt.ComponentOrientation;
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.awt.GridBagConstraints;

import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.border.EmptyBorder;

import java.awt.GridBagLayout;

public class Test extends JFrame {

private JPanel contentPane;
private JButton button2;

public static void main(String[] args) {
    EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            try {
                Test frame = new Test();
                frame.setVisible(true);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    });
}

public Test() {
    setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    setBounds(100, 100, 573, 410);
    contentPane = new JPanel();
    contentPane.setBorder(new EmptyBorder(5, 5, 5, 5));
    contentPane.setLayout(new GridBagLayout());
    contentPane.setComponentOrientation(ComponentOrientation.RIGHT_TO_LEFT);
    setContentPane(contentPane);
    button2 = new JButton("button2");

    GridBagConstraints c = new GridBagConstraints();

    c.gridx = 0;
    c.gridy = 0;

    contentPane.add(button2, c);

}

}
```

this the the output
http://postimg.org/image/bhnzskznj/

Comment: The NetBeans IDE has a nice GUI editor, generating code like above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the answer just asks for a Layout - it's layout recommendation time!

My favourite - http://www.miglayout.com/ which satisfied all my layout needs for my last Swing project. `wrap`, `span x` and `center` layout arguments should be all that is needed to do what your picture does.

Answer (score 1):

This is exactly why absolute layouts are not recommended.

Your best approach will be to use something like `GridBagLayout` which will position the elements and then let them move as the screen resizes and reshapes.

There are plenty of good documentation and tutorials online for `GridBagLayout` that will get you started. You can also use tools built into some IDEs (NetBeans has a good one for example) to let you lay things out graphically.

Comment: thank you but i try more than time with GridBagLayout but i failed,I've some difficulty although i read a lot of tutorials